# Why RunTime Library would have

Tags: windows, mfc, activex

I developed a ocx ,the Runtime Library is setted to "MDd",it runs well,but when I change the Runtime Library  to "MD" something Strange happened，in the main procedures ，the fun AfxGetAppName() returns ocx’s name.

For now,my Compromise approach is use theApp instead AfxGetApp.Because I need get m_nMainWnd.
I found this error in windows10 ,but in windows7 enviroment ,its ok!!!
I just wonder why and what mistake could be.

Comment: This problem have been solved by add "AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());" in main progress.